# How to find folder using website url

Tags: javascript

I have UpFiles folder in my website.

I want to get struploadurl as define in my below code.

It works fine when i run this website at localhost.

But when I deploy my website on different server it will not work So I used "window.location.href" in my code.

```
  function Initialisation() {   
  // Want path same as below like url.
  //  var struploadurl = "http://localhost/MyProject/UpFiles/uploadsave.aspx";      
  // where arr[0] = http , arr[2] =Server Name and arr[3] =Projectname  

    var url = window.location.href;
    var arr = url.split("/");         
    var result = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2] + "//" + arr[3];
    var strPath = result + "/UpFiles/uploadsave.aspx";
    alert(strPath);    

}
```

The problem is that when I use this website with port so it will not work. I want a common solution so I can get struploadurl when my website is deployed without port or also using port.

For Exampple When I deploy my site with "htp://Servrname/MyProject" then above code will work .

When I deploy my site with "htps://ehost.test.com:446/" then above code will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Initialisation() {   
  // Want path same as below like url.
  //  var struploadurl = "http://localhost/MyProject/UpFiles/uploadsave.aspx";      
  // where arr[0] = http , arr[2] =Server Name and arr[3] =Projectname  

    var url = window.location.href;

    var strPath = "/UpFiles/uploadsave.aspx";
    var host = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '');;
    var relativePath = url.substr(host.length+1,url.length - host.length-1);
    var rootFolder = relativePath.substr(0,relativePath.indexOf("/"));
    result = host + "/" + rootFolder + strPath;

    alert(rootFolder);    
    alert(relativePath);    
    alert(result);    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the windows.location object. It has all the properties you need to identify host and port, rather than try and parse the url string manually.

```
host : localhost:800"   
hostname : "localhost"  
href : "http://localhost:800/test/"
pathname : "/test/"
port :"800"
protocol : "http:"  
search : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Initialisation()
{
    var _location = document.location.toString();
    var applicationNameIndex = _location.indexOf('/', _location.indexOf('://') + 3);
    var applicationName = _location.substring(0, applicationNameIndex) + '/';
    var webFolderIndex = _location.indexOf('/', _
    location.indexOf(applicationName) + applicationName.length);
    var webFolderFullPath = _location.substring(0, webFolderIndex);

    alert(webFolderFullPath);
}
```